# Why do my icons change size in every folder? 

Tags: windows-7, icons

Why do my icons change size in every folder?

I want them to be the same.

I reset all folders but still, when I am browsing, some of them are with big icons.
Maybe this is based on the items count in the folder.

Answer (score 4):

First create a folder template (this will be the template that will be applied to all folders).

**For Folders in Windows Explorer**

1. Open the folder in Windows Explorer that you want to change the template on.
2. Click on the **View** menu bar item and click on **Customize This Folder**. (See screenshot below)[image: folder template, change view]

**OR**

OR

3. Right click on a empty space in the Windows Explorer folder window, and click on Customize This Folder. (See screenshot below)
   [image: Right click]
4. Under What kind of folder do you want, select the folder template that you want to have the folder optimized for, and click on OK. (See screenshots below) 
   NOTE: If you wish to also apply this template to all subfolders in this folder, then check that box as well.
   [image: Folder properties 1][image: Change properties 2]

Comment: Cheers wizlog! +1 to you! :)

Comment: i think tat this helps enough, i will make this on my whole hard disk :)